# Node.js Pug: Browser not processing CSS file

Tags: css, node.js, pug

So, I have a `layout.pug`,an `index.pug`, and a `login.pug`.

Format of index.pug and login.pug:

```
extends layout

block content
    //some content
```

This is the code in layout.pug that links the CSS file:

```
link(href='/stylesheets/creative.min.css', rel='stylesheet' ,type='text/css')
```

File structure:

```
public
    stylesheets
         creative.min.css
views
   index.pug
   layout.pug
   login.pug
app.js
```

I have these lines in my `app.js`:

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, './views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './public')));
```

The problem is the CSS styling is being shown when I try to access index but not when I try to access login. While on the login page, I checked the page source and the CSS file was there so it's not as if it can't locate the resource (404). I've spent quite a few hours on this but couldn't get to the root of the problem. I'm a beginner in Node so any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Did you check to see if the CSS file loaded? You can see this in the 'network' section of the developer tools, hit Ctrl-R or Cmd-R and see if it loads or gets a 404. Does the login page contain the same ids and classes that the css file refers to in the index page? It would help to see the css file and the pug files to see if the css file works with that page.

Comment: Yes, I checked that and the CSS file returned a status code of 200 on the networks tab. Also, the navigation bar, as well as the footer, is in the layout.pug file only and I'm using the same layout.pug in both index and login. The navigation/footer on index is getting styled but thats not the case with login.

Comment: try full URI like this: ```http://localhost/stylesheets/creative.min.css``` or relative.